# Is bubbling available for image load events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, event-bubbling

Can I use:

```
window.addEventListner();
```

in some way.

All my images have a `display = 'none'`.

Once the image has loaded,

I want to set `display = 'inline'`

This way I can normalize what is displayed while the image is being downloaded.

In this case, I can not pre-load my images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The `load`/`onload` event does not bubble** ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/load), [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events#Events)), <strike>so what you're asking for is not possible</strike>. You'll have to attach an event handler to each image node, or intercept the event during the capture phase, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Not even "abnormally". One more ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-load

Comment: I would have thought this is what event bubbling was for.  But I guess not, I've updated my question.

Comment: Many other events bubble, like `click`, and that sure is useful. But the fact that `load` doesn't bubble doesn't mean you can't preload your images. Why not create a single function to handle `load` for all images?

Comment: Something like that (although his pure js example won't work, you can't do `imgs.onload` like that, you have to loop)

Answer (score 74):

Use a **capturing** event listener on some parent DOM element like **`document`**, `document.body` or some other wrapper of images you need to observe. You can do this in the **third argument** of element's [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method:

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var tgt = event.target;
        if( tgt.tagName == 'IMG'){
            tgt.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    },
    true // <-- useCapture (or options object)
);
```

The third argument can be either boolean (`true`) or newly added "options" object with a `capture` boolean property (`{ capture: true }`).

Using this approach, you don't have to (re-)attach event handlers while iterating through `document.images` live HTMLCollection or some (re-)queried static NodeList.

This is generally known as *"event delegation pattern"*.

It will also work for dynamically inserted images.

And same applies to [image's `error` loading events.](http://matthewcaruanagalizia.tumblr.com/post/30934181934/error-events-dont-bubble-from-images-and-how-to)

[`addEventListener` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: I never thought to try this for event delegation of image load events. Quite brilliant! And the reason it can't be window: "For legacy reasons, load events for resources inside the document (e.g., images) do not include the Window in the propagation path in HTML implementations"

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('load', function () {
        this.style.display = 'inline';
    });
    if (elem.complete) {
        elem.style.display = 'inline';
    }
});
```

The "load" event will not trigger if the image is incidentally loaded already; thus, we check whether `complete` is already set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Image.onload` event handler but there's no bubbling involved.

```
var i = new Image;
i.onload = function() {
  this.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).show()
})
```

---

Without libraries:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
   imgs.onload = function() {
      this.style.display = 'inline';
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `window.onload` called *after* all images have been loaded?

Comment: @FelixKling not necessarily.

Comment: Is it really possible to apply onload to a NodeList like that?

Comment: @bfavaretto it is not. **The second example is wrong.**

Comment: The 2nd example simply shouldn't work. onload is only applicable to specific objects that have that property -- querySelectorAll returns a node list, so you'd be trying to apply onload to a node list which would never happen.

Answer (score -1):

Since the load event does not bubble, you can lauch your own bubbling event. An example with jQuery:

```
<img src="dog.jpg" onload="$(this).trigger('image-loaded')" />
```